# wso2 lost context to login with tenant`s users

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Don`t work login to the wso2 api manager  (Publisher/Store/Carbon) with tenant`s admin login.
Steps to reproduce:

1) unpack wso2am-1.7.0

2) install mysql jdbc lib

3) add 4 datasource to master-datasources.xml: WSO2CarbonDB, WSO2UM_DB, WSO2REG_DB, WSO2AM_DB to remote mysql database, for example:

> ```
>    <datasource>
>         <name>WSO2REG_DB</name>
>         <description>The datasource used by user manager</description>
>         <jndiConfig>
>             <name>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</name>
>         </jndiConfig>
>         <definition type="RDBMS">
>             <configuration>
>                 <url>jdbc:mysql://192.168.61.224:3306/regdb?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true</url>
>                 <username>regdbuser</username>
>                 <password>bsdfgg8tae</password>
>                 <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
>                 <maxActive>50</maxActive>
>                 <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
>                 <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
>                 <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
>                 <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
>             </configuration>
>         </definition>
>     </datasource>
> ```

4) In file user-mgt.xml changejdbc/WSO2CarbonDB to jdbc/WSO2UM_DB
and add option jdbc/WSO2UM_DB to section  in this file.

5) Start wso2

6) login as admin:admin to /carbon/ and create new tenant  (example.com).

7) login as admin@example.com (always work good)

8) restart wso2am (after restart login as admin@example.com work good)

9) wait 30 minutes

10) login as admin@example.com don`t work.

In log: http://pastebin.com/x5QuFAmU

Comment: Error stack says issue in finding the UM_DB datasource. Please check your datasource configuration are right.

Comment: Please read point 7. datasource configuration are right. login work first 15 minutes after restart.